# Which has the least value?

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, functions, inequality, random-variables

> Which of the following have the least value if $-1 < x < 0$?
>    (A) $-x$
>    (B) $1/x$
>     (C)$-1/x$
>    (D)$1/x^2 $
>    (E)$1/x^3$

I'm not sure what to do, but I'll definitely try. We can break it up into two inequalities: $ x > -1$ and $0 > x$

$\implies -x < 1, 0 < -x$
$\implies -1 < 1/x, 0 < 1/x$
$\implies  1 > 1/x, 0 > -1/x$
$\implies 1/x^2 < 1$
$ \implies 1/x^3 < -1$

So (E) should be correct.

Is this the correct way to go about it?

Comment: The original question ("least value") is unclear because all but (A) are unbounded on the provided interval and two of them have an infimum of $-\infty$ and thus cannot be compared by just looking at the interval. What is probably meant is to order the functions by value under said conditions. This requires not only to look at the individual functions but to look at pairs and compare them, like $-\frac1x < \frac1x$. Also note that displaystyle MathJax (`$$...$$`) introduces a lot of whitespace and should be used carefully and only where it makes sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**
For $x \in (-1, 0)$, order powers of $\pm x$, you should get for e.g.
$$1> -x > x^2> -x^3>x^4>  0 > -x^4> x^3> -x^2> x > -1$$

Now divide throughout by $x^3$, keeping in mind that it is negative, so all signs flip.